# terminal script to quit an app, but ignore need for user input in a dialogue window

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I want to use this command in terminal:
osascript -e 'quit app "ISISClientManager"'
It works but the app has a dialogue box with a yes or no.
Can I automatically have the script select yes.

I am sure this is a basic question. So basic that I could not find an answer in Google.
Thanks,
Ian

Comment: There might be a way to force quit the app.

Comment: correct but. I am trying to avoid the kill command, and want to quit the application politely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First reaction: Whoa, marketing may be well-advised to reconsider that name.

Second reaction: You might be able to do it using the Accessibility API:

If the "Yes" button is the default option:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "MyApp" to activate' -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke return'
```

If it's not the default, it's obviously going to be a tougher time, but if full keyboard access is turned on, you might be able to do it with some combination of tab and space keystrokes (with small delays in between to let the UI catch up). Alternatively, you could get the position of the window, measure the position of the "Yes" button relative to one of its corners, simulate a click event there, and hope the layout doesn't change in some future version of the app.

EDIT: Never mind the above; you can actually get System Events to find the button by name and click it for you:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "MyApp" to click button "Yes" of front window'
```

Or, if the button is in a sheet:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "MyApp" to click button "Yes" of sheet 1 of front window'
```

You will probably need to enable either the Terminal or whatever app you're sending this from in System Preferences -> Privacy -> Accessibility for this to work.